# Adapting count for a prePend folder rename?

Tags: applescript

it's been a while, so my skills have gotten rusty, and I'd appreciate any insight

I have an existing script I'm trying to adjust for a folder rename action that is based on whether or not it contains 10 or 11 characters.

For example, if my projCode is: ABCDE**XX123**, I use:

```
set prePend to text -6 thru -1 of projCode
tell application "System Events" to set name of projectFolder to (prePend & " - " & (get name of projectFolder))
```

But in some cases projCode will have ABCDE**XX1234**

So in order to make it a *little* adaptable, I tried:

```
count projCode
        if projCode count = 11 then
            set prePend to text -6 thru -1 of projCode
        else if projCode count = 10 then
            set prePend to text -5 thru -1 of projCode
```

Obviously it doesn't work. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Your indexing isn’t matching the count - are you talking about the name always being the first 5 characters, and the suffix being what is left?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, the "XX123" and "XX1234" parts of projCode are what's used to rename a folder, since the length of projCode can be either 10 or 11 characters.

Comment: How about `set prePend to text -(get (length of projCode) - 5) thru -1 of projCode`. Or what the @red_menace wrote.

Comment: @Mockman That's perfect, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If the first part (the ABCDE or whatever) will always be 5 characters, then you don’t need to count `projCode` or do any of that other stuff, just get the text after those first 5 characters.  You can mix positive and negative indexes, for example:

```
set prePend to text 6 thru -1 of projCode
```